# jQuery form POST method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, http-post, form-submit

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and trying below code but it always sending data as Query String, I am wanted it to send as POST. What I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="Test" method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnTest" />
  </form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnTest").click(function () {
      var a = "http://xxx.xxx.com/xxx.aspx?target=/IBE.aspx&pub=/kw/English&Tab=1&s=&h=&header=true&footer=true";
      a += "&tid=SB&dpSortBy=0&selacity1=DXB&selddate1=22-Jul-15&seldcity1=KWI&seladate1=25-Jul-15&selAdults=1&selcabinclass=0&selchildren=1&selinfants=1";
      $("#Test").attr('action', a);
      $("#Test").attr('method', 'post');
      $("#Test").submit();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Why not just set the `action` and `method` attributes in the HTML?

Comment: actually we have more than 1 action URL and it depends on the form selection and It is going to be in asp.net.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console? If you're using Chrome, open developer tools and check the Network tab to see if the POST actually happens.

Comment: AFAIK, when you do a traditional post, the post vars must be within the form as elements/inputs.

Comment: Well thing is that I am doing same way it is working for some URL but working for others

Comment: how do you read the parameters in the back-end in this page compared to in the pages that work? and what is the length of the action in this page vs in the pages that work?